# Error when trying to install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, terminal, installation, nokogiri

I'm trying to install Nokogiri to use in a Ruby on Rails application to read XML files. I've been following the instructions on their page for Home Brew 0.9.

When I try and install the libivcon from source as below:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install
```

I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with your version of XCode.  You should make sure you install the newest version of XCode available at https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

It's a rather large download, and it will be done through the App Store.

Comment: thanks eugene, that would never have even crossed my mind.. ill update it and see if it can get it working, thanks